# Angular 'can't resolve' errors when importing thrift library

Tags: angular, thrift

I installed thrift library and his typings file :

```
npm install thrift --save

npm install @types/thrift --save
```

When I import something from thrift like this:

```
import { TFramedTransport, TBinaryProtocol } from 'thrift';
```

And I create a random function to use these imports :

```
deserialize(message: Buffer): void {
  const tTransport = new TFramedTransport(message);
  const tProtocol = new TBinaryProtocol(tTransport);
}
```

Then, I run into 'Can't resolve' errors about thrift and ws libraries.
(child_process, constants, crypto, fs, http, https, net, path, tls, zlib)

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/ws/lib/BufferUtil.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'bufferutil' in 'D:\workspace\dev\thrift_deserialize\my-app\node_modules\ws\lib'

WARNING in ./node_modules/ws/lib/Validation.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'utf-8-validate' in 'D:\workspace\dev\thrift_deserialize\my-app\node_modules\ws\lib'

ERROR in ./node_modules/thrift/lib/nodejs/lib/thrift/connection.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in 'D:\workspace\dev\thrift_deserialize\my-app\node_modules\thrift\lib\nodejs\lib\thrift'
ERROR in ./node_modules/thrift/lib/nodejs/lib/thrift/connection.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'constants' in 'D:\workspace\dev\thrift_deserialize\my-app\node_modules\thrift\lib\nodejs\lib\thrift'
ERROR in ./node_modules/thrift/lib/nodejs/lib/thrift/server.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'constants' in 'D:\workspace\dev\thrift_deserialize\my-app\node_modules\thrift\lib\nodejs\lib\thrift'
ERROR in ./node_modules/thrift/lib/nodejs/lib/thrift/web_server.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'D:\workspace\dev\thrift_deserialize\my-app\node_modules\thrift\lib\nodejs\lib\thrift'
ERROR in ./node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocketServer.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'D:\workspace\dev\thrift_deserialize\my-app\node_modules\ws\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'D:\workspace\dev\thrift_deserialize\my-app\node_modules\ws\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/ws/lib/Sender.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'D:\workspace\dev\thrift_deserialize\my-app\node_modules\ws\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/thrift/lib/nodejs/lib/thrift/web_server.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\workspace\dev\thrift_deserialize\my-app\node_modules\thrift\lib\nodejs\lib\thrift'
ERROR in ./node_modules/thrift/lib/nodejs/lib/thrift/http_connection.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'D:\workspace\dev\thrift_deserialize\my-app\node_modules\thrift\lib\nodejs\lib\thrift'
ERROR in ./node_modules/thrift/lib/nodejs/lib/thrift/web_server.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'D:\workspace\dev\thrift_deserialize\my-app\node_modules\thrift\lib\nodejs\lib\thrift'
ERROR in ./node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'D:\workspace\dev\thrift_deserialize\my-app\node_modules\ws\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocketServer.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'D:\workspace\dev\thrift_deserialize\my-app\node_modules\ws\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/thrift/lib/nodejs/lib/thrift/web_server.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in 'D:\workspace\dev\thrift_deserialize\my-app\node_modules\thrift\lib\nodejs\lib\thrift'
ERROR in ./node_modules/thrift/lib/nodejs/lib/thrift/http_connection.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in 'D:\workspace\dev\thrift_deserialize\my-app\node_modules\thrift\lib\nodejs\lib\thrift'
ERROR in ./node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in 'D:\workspace\dev\thrift_deserialize\my-app\node_modules\ws\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/thrift/lib/nodejs/lib/thrift/server.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'D:\workspace\dev\thrift_deserialize\my-app\node_modules\thrift\lib\nodejs\lib\thrift'
ERROR in ./node_modules/thrift/lib/nodejs/lib/thrift/connection.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'D:\workspace\dev\thrift_deserialize\my-app\node_modules\thrift\lib\nodejs\lib\thrift'
ERROR in ./node_modules/thrift/lib/nodejs/lib/thrift/web_server.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'D:\workspace\dev\thrift_deserialize\my-app\node_modules\thrift\lib\nodejs\lib\thrift'
ERROR in ./node_modules/thrift/lib/nodejs/lib/thrift/server.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in 'D:\workspace\dev\thrift_deserialize\my-app\node_modules\thrift\lib\nodejs\lib\thrift'
ERROR in ./node_modules/thrift/lib/nodejs/lib/thrift/connection.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in 'D:\workspace\dev\thrift_deserialize\my-app\node_modules\thrift\lib\nodejs\lib\thrift'
ERROR in ./node_modules/ws/lib/PerMessageDeflate.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in 'D:\workspace\dev\thrift_deserialize\my-app\node_modules\ws\lib'
```

These errors are strange to me. Does anyone has an idea ?

Here is the package.json if it helps:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.1.0",
    "@stomp/stompjs": "^5.1.0-beta.1",
    "@types/thrift": "^0.10.7",
    "buffer": "^5.2.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "thrift": "^0.11.0",
    "thriftrw": "^3.11.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.12.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^8.10.39",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "^3.1.6"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These modules are only available in the context of Node.js and can not be imported in the browser.
A solution is to tell npm to not import these modules in the browser by adding this in package.json :

```
"browser": {
   "name of the module": false
}
```

So in my case, I added that:

```
  "browser": {
    "child_process": false,
    "crypto": false,
    "constants": false,
    "fs": false,
    "http": false,
    "https": false,
    "net": false,
    "tls": false,
    "zlib": false,
    "path": false,
    "bufferutil": false,
    "utf-8-validate": false
  }
```

I don't know if it's good to do that but it worked.

Comment: There is something not clear for me. Why should npm try to import a module in the browser? I thought only webpack did it

Comment: I said that but it's not clear at all for me. I'm sure you're right ;) Thanks for your clarification.

Comment: I thought webpack did not exist anymore since angular 6.